# Why does jq sometimes require a filter expression, and sometimes not?

Tags: linux, bash, pipe, jq

I have some unformatted JSON files. I want to format them with jq and see the formatted output via less:

```sh
cat *.json | jq | less
```

But it doesn't work. Just shows the jq's help.

O.K., jq needs a filter, minimum a `.`, but...

```sh
cat *.json | jq
```

works for me.

What is the difference? Is this a Bash bug, seeing that parsing the command line is the shell's task? Why does this only happen with jq?

Comment: There's even an open [issue](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/1884) regarding the manual not being explicit about this.

Comment: @BenjaminW: Also relevant are [issue 1028](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/1028) and [issue 220](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/220) (whose resolution changed the undocumented behaviour undocumentedly between versions, at least if I'm understanding git blame correctly),

Comment: @Cyrus are you serious? There I can't make a shorter but complete and reproductible example. If there is a pipe and another command after the jq, then jq stops to work. I don't know, what are you waiting from me...

Comment: @noname: I had assumed that it might be your JSON files but with issue 1028 I think the problem is explained.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`jq` does some things differently if it detects that its output stream is a terminal. For one thing, it colour-codes its output (unless you explicitly turn that option off). But more relevantly to this question, for version 1.5, if it detects that its output stream is a terminal and its input stream is not a terminal and there are no non-option command-line arguments at all, it assumes that you meant to use the filter `.`.

So that's what happens when you type `cat *.json | jq`. In that case, jq's input stream is a pipe (from the `cat` command) but its output stream is the terminal. So it assumes a default filter of `.`.

But when you pipe the output of `jq` through `less`, `jq`'s output stream is no longer a terminal. Now it's a pipe (connected to a `less` process). So the automatic filter `.` is not inserted, and `jq` complains that no filter was provided.

However, if you upgrade to v1.6, you'll find that the behaviour has changed. In v1.6, an invocation without any filter will be adjusted to `.` unless *both* the input stream and the output stream are a terminal. So if you upgrade, you'll find that `cat *.json | jq | less` works roughly the same way as `cat *.json | jq`, except that the output is coloured and, of course, not paged.

By the way, if you wanted to see coloured output with `less` (and you're using Gnu `less`), then you could use the command:

```
cat *.json | jq . -C | less -R   # The . is not necessary with v1.6
```

Comment: I fear, you don't understand me...In a linux bash the jq doesn't work if there is no filter expression in its argument list AND there is a pipe and another command after jq. (it was written to your answer above, not the comment :) )

Comment: @noname: I tried to make the answer a bit more explicit in case it was hard to follow. But basically that's what I said in the answer. In the version you are using, jq will only insert the default filter if its output is a terminal. When you make the output a pipe, it requires a filter so you get an error.

Comment: You could also have pointed-out `cat` is totally useless here.

Comment: @LéaGris: It's just an example of what happens when you pipe into `jq`. Obviously, there are other possible sources of json (curl being particularly common). And, fwiw, if you do specify file inputs, then you must specify a filter, so it makes the whole question moot. So, yeah, I could have used a completely different example of the same phenomenon, but I'm not sure how that would really address OP's question.

Comment: @rici thank you for the help! The key is the stdout device. I've thought, the jq processes the command line's remainder characters as if they were jq's arguments. But not. The jq v1.5 work with no filter only if the output is a terminal. If the output is a pipe or a text file  then it stops working. (`cat x.json | jq` is working, while `nohup cat x.json | jq` isn't)